# Simple substitution of partial waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, mathematical-physics, wavefunction, scattering

> (...)
>   $$
> \psi({\bf r}) \approx \sqrt{n}\sum_l C_l \left[\frac{e^{i(kr - l\pi/2 + \delta_l)} - e^{-i(kr - l\pi/2 + \delta_l)}}{2ikr}\right]P_l(\cos\theta) \tag{1302}
> $$
>   which contains both incoming and outgoing spherical waves. What is the source of the incoming waves? Obviously, they must be part of the large-$r$ asymptotic expansion of the incident wavefunction. In fact, it is easily seen from Eqs. (1291) and (1298) that 
>   $$
> \psi_0({\bf r}) \approx \sqrt{n}\sum_l i^l (2l+1) \left[\frac{e^{i(kr - l\pi/2 )} - e^{-i(kr - l\pi/2 )}}{2ikr}\right]P_l(\cos\theta) \tag{1303}
> $$
>   in the large-$r$ limit. Now, Eqs. (1283) and (1284) give 
>   $$
> \frac{\psi({\bf r}) - \psi_0({\bf r})}{\sqrt{r}} = \frac{\exp(ikr)}{r}f(\theta) \tag{1304}
> $$
>   Note that the right-hand side consists of an outgoing spherical wave only. This implies that the coefficients of the incoming spherical waves in the large-$r$ expansions of $\psi({\bf r})$ and $\psi_0({\bf r})$ must be the same. It follows from Eqs. (1302) and (1303) that 
>   $$
> C_l = (2l+1)\exp[i(\delta_l + l\pi/2)] \tag{1305}
> $$
>   Thus, Eqs. (1302)-(1304) yield 
>   $$
> f(\theta) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(2l+1) \frac{\exp(i\delta_l)}{k}\sin\delta_l P_l(\cos\theta) \tag{1306}
> $$
>   Clearly, determining the scattering amplitude $f(\theta)$ via a decomposition into partial waves (i.e., spherical waves) is equivalent to determining the phase-shifts $\delta_l$.

Can someone plz elaborate the 1305 and 1306 step 
I was badly stuck there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sign of the phase tells you the direction of the wave, so for example

$$
\psi({\bf r}) \approx \sqrt{n} \sum_l C_l \left[\underbrace{\frac{e^{i(kr - l\pi/2 + \delta_l)}}{2ikr}}_{\rm outgoing} - \underbrace{\frac{e^{-i(kr - l\pi/2 + \delta_l)}}{2ikr}}_{\rm incoming}\right]P_l(\cos\theta) \tag{1}
$$

Similarly

$$
\psi_0({\bf r}) \approx \sqrt{n} \sum_l i^l (2l+1)\left[\underbrace{\frac{e^{i(kr - l\pi/2)}}{2ikr}}_{\rm outgoing} - \underbrace{\frac{e^{-i(kr - l\pi/2)}}{2ikr}}_{\rm incoming}\right]P_l(\cos\theta) \tag{2}
$$

Now, you Eq. (1304) states that the difference of the waves $\psi({\bf r}) $ and $\psi_0({\bf r}) $ is an outgoing wave

$$
\frac{\psi({\bf r}) - \psi_0({\bf r})}{\sqrt{n}} = \underbrace{\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}}_{\rm outgoing}f(\theta) \tag{3}
$$

which means that the incoming waves in Eq. (1) and (2) must be equal to each other, that is, each term in the sum associated with an incoming wave must be equal

$$
C_l e^{-i(-l\pi/2 + \delta_l)} = i^l(2l+1)e^{i(l\pi/2)} ~~\Rightarrow~~ \tag{4} C_l e^{-i\delta_l} = i^l(2l + 1)
$$

Now, just remember that $i = e^{i\pi/2}$ so that Eq (4) becomes

$$
C_l=(2l+1)e^{i(l\pi/2 + \delta_l)}
$$